cloudformation resource not able to update for tag update
I am creating a neptune db cluster in aws using cloudformation stackset for a couple of accounts. in few of the accounts, we scaled up and down the neptune db instance class. now when I try to update anything in the neptune db using the cloudformation stack template, it errors out saying
ResourceType:AWS::Neptune::DBInstance, ResourceStatusReason:CloudFormation cannot update a stack when a custom-named resource requires replacing. Rename the db instance and update the stack.


In particular, I am literally just adding tags and even then it spits this error.
The stacks show in-sync when checking for drift and looks like cloudformation doesn't manage it directly since there is no direct link to the neptune cluster from the resources tab in the cloudformation stack.

The error you're encountering is a common issue when dealing with custom-named  resources in AWS CloudFormation. When you scale up and down a Neptune DB instance class outside cloudformation (manually), cloudformation loses its ability to directly manage those resources, especially if you have specified custom names for the DB Instances. that's why when you try to any update, even just adding tags, cloudformation tries to re-create them as part of the update process.
so the issue here:
Custom Names: If you’ve specified custom names for the DB instances (DBInstanceIdentifier), CloudFormation treats them as immutable. Any operation requiring a replacement (even a minor one like tagging) will fail.

and it will keep showing in-sync because cloudformation isn't actively some properties post the manual update.
If possible, avoid specifying the DBInstanceIdentifier in your CloudFormation template. Let CloudFormation assign a name automatically. This way, it can handle replacements and updates more flexibly.
and If the DB instance identifier cannot be changed, then you need to take a snapshot and restore the data, so you do not lose any data during recreation.
or if adding Tags is not a crucial step, try to do it via console or CLI instead.
